# ParseException line 6:5 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'system' in joinSource

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to execute a query in hive and getting the error. I check over and over again but I cannot see any problem.

```
CREATE view sta_v_clean_phrase_longtext (system, `function`, loglockmod, extinfo 
, primarykey, foreignkey, flgprimkey, flgfrgnkey, ref_recn, text_line, copied, 
inserted ) 
AS 
  SELECT system, 
         `function`, 
         loglockmod, 
         extinfo, 
         primarykey, 
         foreignkey, 
         flgprimkey, 
         flgfrgnkey, 
         ref_recn, 
         Concat_ws('', Collect_list(text_line))AS TEXT_LINE, 
         copied 
  FROM  (SELECT system, 
                `function`, 
                loglockmod, 
                extinfo, 
                primarykey, 
                foreignkey, 
                flgprimkey, 
                flgfrgnkey, 
                ref_recn, 
                text_line, 
                copied 
         FROM   phrase_longtext_orc_orc 
         WHERE  primarykey IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP  BY system, 
                   `function`, 
                   loglockmod, 
                   extinfo, 
                   primarykey, 
                   foreignkey, 
                   flgprimkey, 
                   flgfrgnkey, 
                   ref_recn, 
                   text_line, 
                   copied) 
  GROUP  BY system, 
            `function`, 
            loglockmod, 
            extinfo, 
            primarykey, 
            foreignkey, 
            flgprimkey, 
            flgfrgnkey, 
            ref_recn, 
            text_line, 
            copied
```

> ParseException line 6:5 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT'
>   'system' in joinSource

Answer (score 0):

Keep alias name for your **`subquery`** and in create view statement you have **extra column** `inserted` presented which is not present in your select query(i have removed the extra column from below query).

```
hive> CREATE view sta_v_clean_phrase_longtext (system, `function`, loglockmod, extinfo 
, primarykey, foreignkey, flgprimkey, flgfrgnkey, ref_recn, text_line, copied) 
AS 
  SELECT system, 
         `function`, 
         loglockmod, 
         extinfo, 
         primarykey, 
         foreignkey, 
         flgprimkey, 
         flgfrgnkey, 
         ref_recn, 
         Concat_ws('', Collect_list(text_line))AS TEXT_LINE, 
         copied 
  FROM  (SELECT system, 
                `function`, 
                loglockmod, 
                extinfo, 
                primarykey, 
                foreignkey, 
                flgprimkey, 
                flgfrgnkey, 
                ref_recn, 
                text_line, 
                copied 
         FROM   phrase_longtext_orc_orc 
         WHERE  primarykey IS NOT NULL 
         GROUP  BY system, 
                   `function`, 
                   loglockmod, 
                   extinfo, 
                   primarykey, 
                   foreignkey, 
                   flgprimkey, 
                   flgfrgnkey, 
                   ref_recn, 
                   text_line, 
                   copied) t1
  GROUP  BY system, 
            `function`, 
            loglockmod, 
            extinfo, 
            primarykey, 
            foreignkey, 
            flgprimkey, 
            flgfrgnkey, 
            ref_recn, 
            text_line, 
            copied
```

Comment: @zohair, Did the answer helped? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work